# How to use Amazon s3 path for listing amazon s3 folders in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am using Apache Spark for parsing files. I have Amazon S3 path
s3n://my-bucket/amazone-folder/
how to list all files and sub folders using this path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS [Java-SDK documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html) has API details you could use for this purpose:

> Provides an easy way to iterate Amazon S3 objects in a "foreach"
>   statement. For example:

```
for ( S3ObjectSummary summary : S3Objects.withPrefix(s3, "my-bucket", "photos/") ) {
    System.out.printf("Object with key '%s'\n", summary.getKey());
}
```

> The list of S3ObjectSummarys will be fetched lazily, a page at a time,
>   as they are needed. The size of the page can be controlled with the
>   withBatchSize(int) method.

And here is another tutorial explains [how to work with AWS Java SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/welcome.html)